# How to select the same property in a json array? ASP.NET Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I have this string:

```
{
   "timezone":"UTC",
   "serverTime":1669313639361,
   "symbols":[
      {
         "symbol":"ETHBTC",
         "status":"TRADING",
         "baseAsset":"ETH",
      },
      {
         "symbol":"LTCBTC",
         "status":"TRADING",
         "baseAsset":"LTC",
      }
]
```

I want to transform it into a json with only `symbol` properties like:
`["ETHBTC", "LTCBTC"]`

Comment: Can you post a json you want pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your json and use LINQ

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string[] symbols = JObject.Parse(json)["symbols"].Select(x => (string) x["symbol"]).ToArray();
```

UPDATE

if you want a json array

```
JArray symbolsArr = new JArray( JObject.Parse(json)["symbols"].Select(x => (string) x["symbol"]));

//or 

json = symbolsArr.ToString();

//or 

json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(symbols);
```

By you don't need to convert a string array to json if you want to use it in API, you can just return  an array, it will be automatically converted to json my MVC controller action

Comment: that looks great, but how do I convert `string[] symbols` into a json?

Comment: @EL02  ???  What do you mean? can you update your question and put an example?

Comment: I want my function to return a Json so I can call it by AJAX

Comment: Ah I fixed it by using `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(symbols)`. Anyway thanks a lot

Comment: Also didn't know string gets automatically converted to json by the MVC controller action. Good to know

Comment: @EL02 Not only string, but any  instance of  any class.